# Adding a document todatabase on sign in

Tags: html, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Since firebase does not support adding a username to a registered user by default, I try to find a way to write the username and its UserID into the database. Therefore I tried writing a username user id relation into the database. But somehow it never executes the method.
You can find the code below.

HTML template:

```
<mat-tab label="Register">
<div class="registerContainer">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input #usernameRegister (keyup.enter)="register(usernameRegister.value, emailRegister.value, passwordRegister.value)" matInput placeholder="Enter your username">
  </mat-form-field>
  <br>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input #emailRegister (keyup.enter)="register(usernameRegister.value, emailRegister.value, passwordRegister.value)" matInput placeholder="Enter your email">
  </mat-form-field>
  <br>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input #passwordRegister (keyup.enter)="register(usernameRegister.value, emailRegister.value, passwordRegister.value.toString())" matInput placeholder="Enter your password" [type]="hide ? 'text' : 'password'">
    <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>
  <br>
  **<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="register(usernameRegister.value, emailRegister.value, passwordRegister.value)">Register</button>**
</div>
```

Registration operation:

```
register(username:string, email: string, password: string):void{
if (username.length != 0) {
  if (email.length != 0) {
      this.authenticationService.register(username.toString().trim(), email.toString().trim(), password.toString())
        .then((user) => {
          **console.log('database operation');
          this.userService.add(user, username)
            .then(()=>{
              console.log('wrote to database.');
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
              console.log('Error writing to database' + error);
            });**
          user.sendEmailVerification()
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
          this.authenticationService.logout()
            .catch((error)=>{
              console.log(error);
            });
          this.dialogRef.close();
          this.snackBar.open('Registration completed', null, {duration: 1000});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
  }
  else {
    this.snackBar.open('Please enter an email address.', null, {duration: 1000});
  }
}
else {
  this.snackBar.open('Please enter an username.', null, {duration: 1000});
}
```

User model:

```
   export class User implements IFirebaseStorable {
  constructor(
    public uID:string,
    public username:string) {
  }


}
```

Authentication service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  // login with email address
  // returns: Promise<any>
  loginWithEmail(email:string, password:string):Promise<any>{
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  // login via facebook account
  // returns: Promise<any>
  loginWithFacebook():Promise<any>{
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider());
  }

  // login via Github
  // returns: Promise<any>
  loginWithGithub():Promise<any>{
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider());
  }

  // login via google account
  // returns: Promise<any>
  loginWithGoogle():Promise<any>{
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  // login via Twitter
  // returns: Promise<any>
  loginWithTwitter():Promise<any>{
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider());
  }

  // register method
  // parameters: Email - string, Password - string
  // returns: Promise<any>
  **register(username:string, email: string, password: string):Promise<any>{
    return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }**

  // checks whether a user is signed in or not
  // returns: Boolean
  userIsSignedIn():boolean{
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser != null;
  }

  // logout method
  // returns: Promise<any>
  logout() : Promise<any> {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

  // returns: current user with following properties:
  //
  // displayName: string | null;
  // email: string | null;
  // phoneNumber: string | null;
  // photoURL: string | null;
  // providerId: string;
  // uid: string;
  getLoggedInUser():firebase.User{
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
  }

  // send user an email to restore the password
  forgotPassword(email:string):Promise<any>{
    return this.afAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
  }
}
```

User database operation service

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private userCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
  user: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.userCollection = afs.collection<User>('User');
    this.user  = this.userCollection.valueChanges();
  }

  **add(user ,username:string):Promise<DocumentReference>{
    const uID = user.uid.toString();
    const userAdded : User = {uID, username};
    return this.userCollection.add(userAdded);
  }**

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example is written in React through the Redux Actions, but the Javascript is all the same. You want to capture all info from the signup form, send off the signupUserWithEmailAndPassword().then set this data to the database ....

Since you're using Oauth, you will need to capture the response from every version of signin, then create your own custom Object to set into the Database. This was a PITA for me when using different Oauth Clients.

```
export const signupRequest = (email, password, username) => dispatch => {
// ******** The signup actions only trigger for first time users, no need to check database ********
console.log('RECIEVED USER TO SIGNUP', email, password);
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((authData) => {
        // ******** Firebase will create a route with whatever KEY is fed to the .set method ********
        // ******** We dont actually want this to avoid deep nesting ********
        // ******** So we package up our user.account object and .set(account) without any key value pairs ********
        let account = {}
        account.email = email.toLowerCase()
        account.uid = authData.uid
        account.username = username
        firebase.database().ref('users/' + authData.uid).set({
            account
        }).then(() => {
            // ******** Now we need to grap a snapshot from the DB to validate account creation and update the redux store locally ********
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + authData.uid).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
                let updatedUser = snapshot.val();
                console.log(' FOUND THIS USER FROM THE DB after signup', username);
            }).then(() => {
                dispatch(userSet(updatedUser));

            })
        })
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

};